# default is not working on my switch (c++)

Tags: c++, qt4

My problem it's very simple to explain, but I have no idea to solve it.

In my switch statement in the code that you can see below, the default case does not work, but if I remove the last `return "";` works fine.

Like something so simple can lead a person to the path of bitterness?

Greetings and thank you very much in advance

```
QString sim900::loop()  {
    QString text = readSerial();
    if (text != "")
    {
        QStringList commands;
                //       0            1             2              3            4             5
        commands << "+RECEIVE" << " CLOSED" << "REMOTE IP: " << "+CMTI: " << "+CSQ: " << "+CIPSEND=";
        for (int n=0; n<commands.length(); n++)
        {
            if (text.indexOf(commands[n]) != -1)
                switch (n)
                {
                case 0:
                    SocketReceive(text, false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    DropClient(text);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    NewClient(text);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    EstadoRed(text);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ReadyToSend(text);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (n == commands.length()-1)
                        return text;
                }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Isn't the length of commands 6? And don't you have 0-5 cases which you handle? And don't you continue the loop until n < commands.length()?

Comment: The code search if something string of command is contained in text, and for this reason, if in the last item it does not find, return the text.

Comment: OK, but commands.length() = 6. commands.length() - 1 = 5 a case you already handle and break from. IOW, based on your loop it won't work. Change the loop to start at some large value of n, remove the condition of commands.length() and the `if` and see what happens.

Comment: Think that n starts with 0, and the first list starts with 0 too, and n never be 6. And when I remove the last return ""; all works fine.

Comment: I try hundred of things, and the only thing that works, is removing the last return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this...

```
  for(int n = 1; n < 2; ++n) {
        switch (n) {
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Whoops!";
        }
    }
```

this will print "Whoops!" once. That's because I start outside the cases which I handle - a default case.

Now, consider this...

```
    int commandsLength = 6;
    for(int n = 0; n < commandsLength; ++n) {
        switch (n) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                if (n == commandsLength - 1)
                    std::cout << "Whoops!";
        }
    }
```

and the fact the `default` case can never be reached because I handle the `5` case and due to the condition on the `for` `n` cannot be `>= 6`. This is the situation you've created for yourself.

Comment: @jularaXD, sorry I can't see what you're showing me. I'm showing you that the way you've coded yours, which I simulate, is wrong. Change `n = 0` to `n = -1` in my `for` and see "Whoops!". Or change the condition to `n <= commandsLength`; that'd work too.

Comment: Now I understand you and see my mistake.

Comment: I think when the program could not find a return, it had jumped to return within the default, which is why I worked when erasing the last return; 
Can be possible?

Comment: @jularaXD, That I don't know, but it sounds pretty unlikely. Ideally you'd get a compiler error about not having a solid return based on the type you declared. It may have auto returned text I guess; that's something you can verify with a breakpoint on the default return and remove the other.  If that's the case hard to find bugs are likely.

Comment: @jularaXD - no problem. BTW - feel free to show appreciation by up-voting and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: I'm too noob to vote your answer, but I managed to mark your answer as correct.